# Using PGP with an unknown entity

Tags: security, authentication, pgp

I'm currently researching on PGP and authentication schemes.

Let's say i'm communicating with someone who claims to be an admin of a ftp site. (say, his email address is admin@genuine-website.com)

Assume both of us have one another's PGP public keys.

Say first, we exchange fingerprints and verify them (by directly transmitting them and not using out of band authentication like phone/sms). In the second step, we exchange a signed message and then verify the signature.

Are these two steps good enough to establish authenticity?

By means of this fictitious example, the basic question i'm trying to ask is whether these steps are "enough" or should i opt for another mutual authentication scheme on top of this?

Comment: Off topic here, should go to [security.se].

Answer (score 0):

That's enough, however the most tricky is to verify fingerprints.
For PGP this is done via cross-signing keys with other keys. While in X.509 it is hierarchical structure (top CAs and signed by them certificates), in PGP it is done as 'web of trust'.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. To verify fingerprints, can't we use a zero knowledge based protocol to confirm whether they are the same? (instead of sending them across on the network?)

Comment: No, you should verify fingerprints via the trusted protocol. Otherwise you cannot rely on that key(s).

Comment: I thought verification meant that one runs the verify command on his machine to get the fingerprint from the other party's public key. He then compares it by asking the other party whether the output he got matches the fingerprint they have. The other party follows the same process.

Comment: The problem is how to securely ask other party about the fingerprint :)

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not good enough. A man-in-the-middle can substitute his public keys for yours and your partner's, and then do the same thing with the fingerprints so that everything appears to check out okay.

You'll need to use PGP's web of trust, or exchange fingerprints in another medium that you trust, to verify the public key you received is authentic.

Comment: That's exactly what i was afraid of! Thanks but can't we use a zero knowledge based protocol to confirm whether the fingerprints are the same? (instead of sending them across on the network?)

Comment: For sharing public keys, we can use email or post them on a keyserver and share the link via email. Any comments?

Comment: A key server could work, if you trust a key that it uses to sign responses with. This problem is actually at the root of a very big issue with security on the web: your browser ships with a set of built-in PKI authorities that could be tampered with and you'd never know; there's really no distribution of the root authority fingerprints via secure media.